# using two nodes at a time

Tags: ros, can

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have two nodes 1) which receives CAN messages from uc board to ROS (publisher) 2) which transmit CAN messages to uc board (subscribing). I need to run both the nodes in order to to these two tasks.
Now I am supposed to do: if receive node receives message, it should transmit a CAN message. How can I combine these two nodes or how can use one node information by other?. any suggestions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252489/using-two-nodes-at-a-time/) by [newbieros](https://answers.ros.org/users/23682/newbieros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you could implement the nodes as nodleds understand then nor those in an node, or you define a new topic which is your sync signal. if you receive a can message then you publisch to the sync topic and if the send node receive a sysnc topic then you write your CAN message.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0